# Extracting/Calculating P-Value from Logit Regression

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression

is it possible to extract the 2 tailed P value (P>|z|) from a logit model? I've tried some stat packages but have not been successful. If there is no package for this, how would I go about calculating it manually in Python? I found what would be a good reference [here](https://gist.github.com/rspeare/77061e6e317896be29c6de9a85db301d) but it's kind of confusing what they are doing.

My logit regression looks like:

`model = smf.logit("pricing_exception ~ pr_b + pr_h + pr_a + pr_m + pr_ai",              data = testdata[testdata['id'] == "BCL"]).fit()`

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@Nanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18465851/nanu)'s question post.

> ```
> walds_BCL = BCL_model.wald_test_terms(scalar = False)
> pvalue_BCL = walds_BCL.summary_frame()
> ```
>
> This turns it into a df so it can be easily accessible. Hope this helps someone!